# Display output from Python in Node.js server

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I want to display all the output from `pokecli.py` on a web page that can be accessed from `http://192.168.32.100:8081`. Currently I am getting a "connection refused" from Chrome, but no errors when running `node myscript.js`.

I am new to Node and I am not exactly sure if this is right. I want to display the output in real time. I know this is possible even without NGINX since I can get output from the following example code by opening `http://192.168.32.100:8080`:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, '192.168.0.251');
console.log('Server running at http://192.168.0.251:8080/');
```

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Options to be used by request
var options = {
   host: '127.0.0.1',
   port: '8081'
};

// Callback function is used to deal with response
var callback = function(response){
   // Continuously update stream with data
   var body = '';
   response.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
      PythonShell.run('pokecli.py', function (err) {

            if (err) throw err;
                console.log('finished');
            });
   });

   response.on('end', function() {
      // Data received completely.
      console.log(body);
   });
}
// Make a request to the server
var req = http.request(options, callback);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!'); // This will serve your request to '/'.
});

app.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8081!');
 });

req.end();
```

Comment: Do you have a web server running on your computer?

Comment: @JohnGordonYes, I have NGINX running.

Comment: Does the incoming request appear in the web server's log?